# How to tell google i have different languages of website on different domains

Tags: html, seo, google-search-console

Im setting up a new website luxiron.si and luxiron.eu. The .eu version is in english and .si is in slovene. How can i tell google that they are the same sites with same content only in different languages?

Also is this a good idea reagarding SEO google rankings or should i just add both languages on one domain.

I already tried indexing both of them with google search console.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Programming related SEO questions (e.g. the first paragraph which asks how to express something in HTML, even if it does it in SEO-specific terms) *are* on-topic for Stackoverflow. Opinion based questions (like the second paragraph) are not.

Answer (score 0):

State the language of a page using the `lang` attribute:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<html lang="sl">
```

State that an alternative version of a page is available with `<link>` and use `hreflang` to describe the language of the target document.

```
<!-- On https://luxiron.eu/example point to the translated version with -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sl" href="//luxiron.si/example">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

But is it better for my SEO rankings to only have one domain (.eu) than having two of them?

Comment: @patrikpeternel  — That's not a programming related question. You could ask it on the webmasters stackexchange.